# How to take a json file as a default document of directory on Apache?

Tags: json, apache, default, mime-types, document-root

I built a simple Apache server on my Pc, and I want to place a json file under one specific directory(just like htdocs/configCenter/jsonConfig/). When I visit the /configCenter/jsonConfig/ in browser, I wanna see my json file directly. How to make it?
Thank you!

Comment: Use the `DirectoryIndex` directive in the directory's htaccess file or apache conf

Answer (score 0):

> Use the DirectoryIndex directive in the directory's htaccess file or apache conf